# How to understand "(Num b) => length :: [a] -> b" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am reading [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101), and come across the following word:

> For instance, the length function has a type declaration of length :: [a] -> Int instead of having a more general type of (Num b) => length :: [a] -> b.

How to understand "`(Num b) => length :: [a] -> b`" here? Shouldn't it be "`length :: (Num b) => [a] -> b`"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right: it's an error in the book and should read as you suggest.